# Как сравнить две даты на разницу между ними в шесть месяцев? (котлин, андроид)

Tags: kotlin, localdate

Есть data1 и data2. Нужно просто сравнить на true или false разницу между ними в 6 **месяцев** (а не например в 182 дня).
И если эта разница составляет менее шести месяцев - то выполнить функцию.
Что-то вроде

```
fun sidSixMounts_E(): Boolean {
    val periodSixMounts = Period.between(data1, date2)
    when (periodSixMounts.toString().equals("P6M")) {
        true -> return true
        false -> return false
    }
}
```

или

```
fun sidSixMounts(): Boolean {
    val periodSixMounts = Period.between(data1, date2)
    if (periodSixMounts.toString() == "P6M") return true
    else return false
}
```

Пока не могу проверить, не за компьютером. Если оба варианта рабочие - какой лучше?

Comment: `return Period.between(firstDate, secondDate).months.absoluteValue < 6` если нужно строгое равенство, а не больше / меньше, то замените `<` на `==`

Comment: Варианты, которые привели Вы некорректны, а кроме того, вообще не отличаются в плане внутренней логики

Comment: для запуска функции период должен быть *меньше* 6 месяцев. А почему не корректны? кратко хотя бы если можно.

Comment: Мой вариант из первого коммента вернет `true` тогда и только тогда, когда между датами строго меньше 6 месяцев (в любую сторону)

Comment: понял, ваш код лаконичнее и экономнее

Comment: а вот так правильно будет? на ошибки не смотрите, пока переменные не добавил https://i.ibb.co/tBtfgS5/beet.png

Comment: Вроде правильно. Но я бы таки использовал `if`. `val srok = if (Period.between(firstDate, secondDate).months.absoluteValue < 6) 1 else 2`

Comment: на котлине вроде все агитируют за when... Но ваш код опять более краткий и экономный. Спасибо!

Comment: `when` используют для всего, кроме однократной проверки `true` или `false`. Если проверок в условии много, или проверяется что-то другое, то `when`. Для простейшего случая - `if`. Обычно такого правила все придерживаются

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov, возник небольшой баг ) так как ТЗ с моей стороны оказалось не совсем правильным,  просьба посмотреть вопрос - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1333831/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для работы с периодами следует учесть, что внутри они не являются строками, а хранят числовые значения, которые куда удобнее сравнивать.

Возьмем Ваш первоначальный код:

```kotlin
fun sidSixMounts_E(): Boolean {
    val periodSixMounts = Period.between(data1, date2)
    when (periodSixMounts.toString().equals("P6M")) {
        true -> return true
        false -> return false
    }
}
```

Сравнение можно переписать следующим образом:

`when (periodSixMounts.months == 6)`

Так как нужно не сравнение на равенство, а проверка на **меньше**, то еще раз изменим строку:

`when (periodSixMounts.months < 6)`

Учтем, что период бывает как положительный, так и отрицательный (в зависимости от порядка дат):

`when (periodSixMounts.months.absoluteValue < 6)`

Ну и помимо сути вопроса добавлю, что в таких случаях, когда внутри `when` стоит логическое выражение, лучше применять `if`. Код получается намного короче и понятнее при чтении.

В данном случае и вовсе можно вернуть само логическое выражение

Итоговый вариант:

```kotlin
fun sidSixMounts_E(): Boolean {
    val periodSixMounts = Period.between(data1, date2)
    return periodSixMounts.months.absoluteValue < 6
}
```

Comment: спасибо за разбор полетов ) Всё буду использовать ваш лаконичный код в стиле котлина в виде `if val srok = if (Period.between(firstDate, secondDate).months.absoluteValue < 6) 1 else 2`. Только в принципе в датах не будет отрицательного значения, они идут в порядке увеличения, значит могу использовать код без "абсолют" `if val srok = if (Period.between(firstDate, secondDate).months < 6) 1 else 2` . И не надо лишнюю переменную объявлять (periodSixMounts )