# Как правильно рассчитать количество месяцев в периоде больше года при сравнении дат? (котлин, андроид)

Tags: android, kotlin

Данный код определяет количество месяцев между датами, но если между датами разница больше одного года, то код не считает общее число месяцев, а выводит только остаток месяцев от года, то есть не 14 месяцев, а всё равно 2 месяца. Нужно чтобы выводилось полное количество месяцев

```
Period.between(data1, date2).months.absoluteValue
```

Comment: Посмотри вот здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48950145/java-8-calculate-months-between-two-dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы неверно понимаете поведение `Period`. Он вам говорит:

```
val p = Period.between(LocalDate.now(), LocalDate.now().plusMonths(14))
println(p) // P1Y2M
```

**Один год и Два месяца**. Вы же читаете только месяцы, игнорируете годы.

Но есть еще вот такой метод, думаю это как раз то, что вам надо.

```
println(p.toTotalMonths()) // 14
```

Который собственно все что делает:

```
return years * 12L + months;
```

Comment: Понимаю, что период считает остаток от месяцев, просто поискал в хелпах, но вашего способа не увидел. Спасибо! А что за L возле 12?

Comment: @jurvrn, long literal: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html